# Solving $\sum_i a_i p_i^k=b_0$ for $k$

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning

Is there a fast way to find $k$ in the equation below for positive reals $a_i,p_i,b_0$?

$$\sum_i^d a_i p_i^k=b_0$$

Constraint of the problem means $p_i$ is very close to 1, so $p_i \approx \exp(p_i-1)$, solving the following is equivalent

$$\sum_i^d a_i \exp((p_i-1) k)=b_0$$

My current solution with `FindRoot` and `Compile` on a representative example is below. `FindRoot` is generic, so I'm wondering if there are a problem-specific tools in Mathematica to speed this up

```
d = 20000;
b0 = 0.01;

traceNormalize[x_] := x/Total[x];
a = traceNormalize@ConstantArray[1., d];
p = 1 - traceNormalize[1./Range[d]];

fwd[k_] := Sum[a[[i]] p[[i]]^k, {i, 1, d}];
bwd[b_] := k /. FindRoot[fwd[k] == b, {k, 1}]
With[{b = b0}, Print["correctness test: ", fwd[bwd[b]] == b]];
Print["original: ", bwd[b0] // Timing] (* 1.87 *)

fwdCompiled = Compile[{{k, _Real}}, Sum[a[[i]] p[[i]]^k, {i, 1, d}]];
bwdCompiled[b_] := k /. FindRoot[fwdCompiled[k] == b, {k, 1}]
Print["compiled: ", bwdCompiled[b0] // Timing] (* 0.602 *)

(* Use p == exp(p-1) approximation *)
fwdApprox[k_] := Sum[a[[i]] Exp[(p[[i]] - 1) k], {i, 1, d}];
bwdApprox[b_] := k /. FindRoot[fwdApprox[k] == b, {k, 1}]
Print["approximate: ", bwdApprox[b0] // Timing] (* 0.772 *)
```

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-series-findroot-improve.nb)

Motivation: eliminating performance bottleneck when ranking optimization problems by difficulty, [background](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2362355)

Comment: Note that `Sum[a[[i]] p[[i]]^k, {i, 1, d}]` can be simplified to `a.p^k` and `Sum[a[[i]] Exp[(p[[i]] - 1) k], {i, 1, d}]` can be simplified to `a . Exp[(p - 1) k]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing your own "Newton's Method" is even faster (although that likely has fewer guardrails than `FindRoot`).

```
d = 20000;
b0 = 0.01;

traceNormalize[x_] := x/Total[x];
a = traceNormalize@ConstantArray[1., d];
p = 1 - traceNormalize[1./Range[d]];

kprev = 1;  (* Starting value *)
delta = 0.01;  (* How close two successive values need to be to stop *)
k = kprev + 2 delta;
AbsoluteTiming[
  n = 0;
  While[Abs[k - kprev] > delta && n < 1000,
    n = n + 1;
    kprev = k;
    k = k - (a . p^k - b0)/(a . (Log[p] p^k));
  ];
 {n, k}]
(* {0.0048474, {11, 639511.}} *)
```

Comment: Doesn't `FindRoot` implement Newton's method? (using the `Jacobian` option)

Comment: It does but I didn't find any of the listed methods producing faster results.  In fact all of the results were similar to what you listed in your question.  But I certainly might not have hit upon the right fine-tuning of the method parameters.

Comment: Thanks, that's a huge speed-up! Weird that `FindRoot` is so slow. Since the number of function evaluations is similar to your `Newton's` approach (I saw 15), there must be some overhead happening in `FindRoot`. I [looked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4650738/inverse-of-transform-fx-sum-an-exp-x-an) a bit for a problem-specific approach, but `FindRoot` so far seems fastest

Comment: For that other question on *Math.StackExchange*, how fast is using `FindRoot` for 10,000 values of $y$?  A brute-force Newton's method on all 10,000 in *Mathematica* takes 3.3 seconds.  I suspect that also incorporating `Interpolation` would result in further reductions in execution time.

Comment: `FindRoot` is actually couple of seconds. Summation approach suggests a way to compute all points as one using integral transform but seems painfully [slow](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/281795/inverting-laplace-transform-numerically-for-a-set-of-points) right now, so Newton's seems the best way

Comment: Using a home-grown Newton's method for a set in interpolation points, takes about 0.06 seconds for 10,000 values of $b$ for your *Math.StackExchange* question.  But that's not the requested approach.

Answer (score 5):

Taking advantage of @BobHanlon 's comment and using interpolation, one can determine the minimum and maximium possible values of $k$ to get a quicker approximation (maybe 15 to 20 times faster).

Basic setup:

```
d = 20000;
b0 = 0.01;

traceNormalize[x_] := x/Total[x];
a = traceNormalize@ConstantArray[1., d];
p = 1 - traceNormalize[1./Range[d]];
```

Find minimum and maximum possible values for $k$:

```
minmax = Transpose[MinMax[#] & /@ {a, p}]
(* {{0.00005, 0.904587}, {0.00005, 0.999995}} *)
kminmax = Log[b0/(#[[1]] d)]/Log[#[[2]]] & /@ minmax
(* {45.9245, 965308.} *)
```

Construct an interpolation function and then use `FindRoot`:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 f = Interpolation[{#, a . p^#} & /@ 
     Range[kminmax[[1]], kminmax[[2]], (kminmax[[2]] - kminmax[[1]])/100]];
 FindRoot[{f[k] == b0}, {{k, Mean[kminmax]}}]]
(* {0.0305321, {k -> 639511.}} *)
```

I was more than a bit surprised that the starting value for $k$ didn't seem to matter much.  In other words, using the default value of 1 seemed to do just as well as something close to the final value.

Comment: Interesting. It's a bit counter-intuitive that this improves speed so much. You evaluate the function 100 times to construct interpolation. But in the original formulation, `FindRoot` only calls the function 15 times: ```With[{b = 0.01},
 e = 0;
 val = k /. 
    FindRoot[fwdApprox[k] == b, {k, 1}, EvaluationMonitor :> e++] // 
   Timing;
 Print[e];
 val
 ]```