# Inverting Laplace transform numerically for a set of points

Tags: numerical-integration, integral-transforms

Computing inverse of Laplace transform numerically in Mathematica seems very slow and requires $k$ calls for $k$ points. Is there a faster way to do it for a set of $k$ points, ie $k\approx 1000$?

```
(* example hard to invert algebraically *)
fwd = LaplaceTransform[-((2 y)/Sqrt[1 - (-1 + 2 y)^2]), y, s]
xvals = {0.1, 0.5};
InverseLaplaceTransform[fwd, s, #] & /@ xvals // Timing (* 6.05569 *)
```

PS: This [reference](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/%28SICI%291099-1204%28199805/06%2911%3A3%3C153%3A%3AAID-JNM299%3E3.0.CO%3B2-C) reduces inverse Laplace Transform to inverse FFT

Comment: This appears to be specific to your version. v13.2 and v13.2.1 handle 1000 points in a fraction of a second.

Comment: OK, I've upgraded and I suspect `13.2` is cheating by calling algebraic inversion. When it's not possible it's just as slow -- ```fwd = Sin[s];
xvals = {0.1, 0.5, .9};
yvals = InverseLaplaceTransform[fwd, s, #] & /@ xvals;
ListPlot[Transpose[{xvals, yvals}]]```

Comment: Have you seen [`ResourceFunction["NInverseLaplaceTransform"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/NInverseLaplaceTransform/) ?

Comment: @flinty thanks, although it seems even slower for the example in question

Comment: Maybe this helps only need to translate from Matlab to MMA. See: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32824-numerical-inversion-of-laplace-transforms-in-matlab?s_tid=FX_rc2_behav#version_history_tab go to tab: Functions->INVLAP.m .